# PHP foreach loop doesn't run all the iterations. I have 1500 users but it only executes for about 1000 users, then gives back a blank page

Tags: php, foreach, kohana-3.3

This gets all users and stores them in an array
For each of those users, generate email and SMS.
There is also selection of the email template to be used.
This only generates like 1000 emails and SMS, stops execution and returns a blank view with no error. What could be the problem?

```
     //Send invitations 
 $users_to_invite = $this->catalogue->fetch_users_to_invite();//1500 users
 foreach ($users_to_invite as $user_data) {
     // Select email template                       
     $email_template = SECURITY_AUCTION_INVITE;

     if ($catalogue_data[0]['payment_mode'] == 'D') {
         $email_template = DEDUCTIBLE_AUCTION_INVITE;
         if ($catalogue_data[0]['security_mode'] == SECURITY_MODE_BANK_DEPOSIT) {
             $email_template = DEDUCTIBLE_AUCTION_INVITE_BANK_DEPOSIT;
         }
     } 
     // Generate SMS
     $sms_msg = $this->communication_template->invitation_sms($catalogue_data, $user_data);
     // Generate email
     $this->username = $this->communication_template->invitation_mail($catalogue_data, $user_data);

     $this->replace_variable = array_merge($this->replace_variables,$this->username);
     // Generate SMS
     Commonfunction::send_text_message($user_data['msisdn'], $sms_msg);

     // Generate mail to user
     $mails = Commonfunction::get_email_template_details($email_template,$this->replace_variable,SEND_MAIL_TRUE);
}
```

Comment: How long does it take? Is it timing out?

Comment: I believe you must find a way to send only500 emails at a time. I guess your function exceed max execution time set in php.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it takes about 30 seconds then the blank screen. No error given out

Comment: Sounds like it is timing out. The default time limit is 30s. You can increase it in your script with `set_time_limit()`.

Comment: @nikistag some correction, it just generates the email, saves in the db. No sending here. Let me update

Comment: @Don'tPanic in production server, do we have have to set the time limit? Then I thought it should throw the max execution time exceeded error.